# Как добавить изменение версии C# прямо в коде в самой Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Цитирую:

> Вам нужно будет использовать свойство для условия, которое доступно в
> самом начале сборки.  В вашем случае вы должны указать
> MSBuildProjectExtension:
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>   <LangVersion Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)'=='.csproj'">9.0</LangVersion>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```
>
> Полный набор доступных свойств см. в разделе Зарезервированные и
> общеизвестные свойства MSBuild. ProjectExt определяется только в конце
> определения сборки и поэтому недоступен в Directory.Build.props,
> который импортируется в проект очень рано.

---

Бывает нужно изменить версию `C#` и чтобы не дропать в папку какие-то доп `.drops` или копаться в файле `.csproj` и там менять версию, сделать чтобы студия сама смогла определять нужную версию и предлагала изменить проект под нужную версию.
На другом ПК в студии 2019 есть такая возможность, но установил на другом пк студию, нету такой возможности изменять, а это очень удобно.
*Если версия выше, чтобы автоматически предлагала изменять на последнюю версию!*

Я так полагаю нужно где-то в `MSBuild` копаться или в папке установленной Visual Studio ?
[Вот в конце пример как студия предлагает изменять версию, мне так и нужно!](https://andrey.moveax.ru/post/csharp-version-select)